# Is this function strictly convex and why?

Tags: convex-analysis

Is this function **strictly** convex?

$(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6-30)^2+(x_7+x_8+x_9+x_{10}+x_{11}-24)^2+(x_1+x_7+x_8+x_4-14)^2$

variables are $x_i$ and we have $1 \le x_i \le 9$.

Comment: Can you change it to MathJax/Latex?

Comment: Done..........!

Comment: It should be clear that the answer is no: a strictly convex function can be at most a unique minimiser but this function has plenty.

Comment: I forgot  to add the constraint $1 \le x_i \le 9$.

Comment: But it is a sum of x^2 functions which are strictly convex!

Comment: With the constrains, it is not so clear whether or not it will be strictly convex.

Comment: @WillM.: The constraints do not matter. A quadratic function is strictly convex on $\mathbb R^n$ iff it is strictly convex on any (small) ball.

Comment: @gerw OP has a closed set, not an open one, so I am not sure if the  second derivative test still applies.

Comment: But the set has an interior point. Hence the same argument is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: fix all variables but $x_2$ and $x_3$ and have a look at the two-dimensional function (depending only on $x_2$ and $x_3$.

Note that a sum of squares is not always strictly convex, i.e., $(x_1,x_2) \mapsto x_1^2$.